# Angularjs app.js getting URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularjs, do we have anything on app.js level to determine the application URL.

I know inside the application, we can use $location.path() to determine it, but app.js we dont have $location

Basically, the need is to enable and disable the console logging for the application using a URL param switch.

Idea is

http://www.test-website.com/ - Will run and not fetch console.log

http://www.test-website.com?debug=1 - Will run and fetch console.log (s) for the application.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you can use `$location` in any function that includes it as a dependency.  Without any code, it's hard to know what you are doing, but there is no reason why `$location` would not be available to code inside an app.js file.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always in javascript - in a browser - call `window.location`. It will return an object that holds the hostname, pathname, port and protocol - amongst other properties and methods.

Calling `window.location.search` will return `"?debug=1"` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $location service in app.config() block but you can use it in app.run() which can also be present in app.js.